# INNER JOIN And Row_Num() Function Problems

Tags: sql-server-2005, inner-join, row-number

I have a stored procedure which does sorting pnd Paging like the [Sorting Custom Paged Results of](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032206-1.aspx) by Scott Michell.

I have two tables: `Article` and `Category`. My stored procedure works fine for `Article` table, but I want add a column from the `Category` table into the query (Inner Join I mean ).

Actually I can't do it like Scott Michell has done, because there are some columns that are similar in both tables (when I do like Scott all the time I get "Ambiguous Column Error").

My stored procedure without inner join is :

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Articles_SelectByCategoryId]
    @CategoryId int,
    @startRowIndex int = -1,
    @maximumRows int = -1,
    @sortExpression nvarchar(50),
    @recordCount int = NULL OUTPUT
AS
    IF (@recordCount IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @recordCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                            FROM [dbo].[Articles] 
                            WHERE [CategoryId] = @CategoryId)
        RETURN
    END

    IF LEN(@sortExpression) = 0
       SET @sortExpression = 'Id'

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT [Id], [AddedDate], [AddedBy], [CategoryId],
                       [Title], [Abstract], [Body]
                FROM
                    (SELECT 
                         [Id], [AddedDate], [AddedBy], [CategoryId],
                         [Title], [Abstract], [Body],
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @sortExpression + ') as RowNum
                     FROM [dbo].[Articles]
                     WHERE CategoryId = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @CategoryId) + ') as CategoryIdInfo
         WHERE ((RowNum between (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + ') AND ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + ' + ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @maximumRows) + ' - 1) 
   OR ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + ' = -1 OR ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @maximumRows) + ' = -1)'

      -- Execute the SQL query
      EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

My `Category` table is :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category]
(
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [AddedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [AddedBy] [nvarchar](250) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL,
   [Title] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL,
   [Importance] [int] NOT NULL,
   [Description] [nvarchar](300) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
   [ImageUrl] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Category] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

My `Article` table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Articles]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AddedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [AddedBy] [nvarchar](250) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](255) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Abstract] [nvarchar](4000) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
    [Body] [nvarchar](max) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [ReleaseDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ExpireDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Approved] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Listed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CommentEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [OnlyForMembers] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ViewCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Votes] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalRating] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Articles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I don't know how to add The "Title" column of "Category" table into query.

If my `Category` table hadn't similar fields, surely this query works :

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = 
'SELECT
    [Id],
    [AddedDate],
    [AddedBy],
    [CategoryId],
    [Title],
    [Abstract],
    [Body],
    ArticleTitle
FROM
    (SELECT 

    [Id],
    [AddedDate],
    [AddedBy],
    a.[CategoryId],
    [Title],
    [Abstract],
    [Body],
    b.Title as CategoryTitle ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @sortExpression + ') as RowNum

    FROM  [dbo].[Articles] a INNER JOIN Category b on a.CategoryId = b.Id

    WHERE a.CategoryId = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @CategoryId) + '
    ) as CategoryIdInfo
```

If you want to Test you can download the [Attachment(Tables and StoredProcedure)](http://sites.google.com/site/dindarbiz/file-cabinet/StoredProcedureAndTables.rar?attredirects=0&d=1)
Thank you

Comment: Ambiguous Column Error - If you have the same column name then you can qualify the column name with the table name / alias so as it is not ambiguous

Comment: Mostafa - Ive added a second answer, with essentially the same code but based on your example sproc. I'll tidy this up if it works for you, I just added the new answer for clarity (and because I'm worried about my original answer going Community Wiki)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works perfectly on your provided tables - with no data in them but that shouldn't make a difference since I just want to prove the query execution, not the results.

Things to note with this code:

**The sort expression must include an alias**

```
SET @sortExpression = 'a.Id'
```

**All duplicated columns must be aliased**

Note how a.[Id],  a.[AddedDate], a.[AddedBy], a.[CategoryId], a.[Title], b.[Title] are all aliased

**Column names must match between the inner and outer queries**

You had a column name of ArticleTitle in your outer select, but a column of CategoryTitle in your inner select. That would never work.

```
DECLARE @SortExpression nvarchar(100)
SET @sortExpression = 'a.Id'        

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) 
SET @sql =  
'SELECT 
    [Id], 
    [AddedDate], 
    [AddedBy], 
    [CategoryId], 
    [Title], 
    [Abstract], 
    [Body], 
    CategoryTitle 
FROM 
    (SELECT  

    a.[Id], 
    a.[AddedDate], 
    a.[AddedBy], 
    a.[CategoryId], 
    a.[Title], 
    [Abstract], 
    [Body], 
    b.Title as CategoryTitle , 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @sortExpression + ') as RowNum 

    FROM  [dbo].[Articles] a INNER JOIN Category b on a.CategoryId = b.Id 

    WHERE a.CategoryId = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @CategoryId) + ' 
    ) as CategoryIdInfo' 

      -- Execute the SQL query 
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: David thanks a ton ! You helped me a lot . If i spend one more day i couldn't solve my problem . What do you think about deleting our previous Comments , Because the answer is this post .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the code below?

This uses the AS keyword to give unique names to columns in your subquery, and aliases to allow unambiguous references to columns within the subquery join itself.

Also note that **ALL** references to columns that are ambiguous must be aliases, this includes in your case the @sortExpression that you are dynamically injecting.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Articles_SelectByCategoryId]   
 @CategoryId int,   
 @startRowIndex int = -1,   
 @maximumRows int = -1,   
 @sortExpression nvarchar(50),   
 @recordCount int = NULL OUTPUT   

AS   

IF (@recordCount IS NOT NULL)   
 BEGIN   
  SET @recordCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Articles] WHERE [CategoryId] = @CategoryId   
 )   
  RETURN   
 END   

IF LEN(@sortExpression) = 0   
   SET @sortExpression = 'Id'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) 
SET @sql =  
'SELECT 
 [Id], 
 [AddedDate], 
 [AddedBy], 
 [CategoryId], 
 [Title], 
 -- CategoryTitle refers to the column name declared by that AS inside the subquery
 CategoryTitle
 [Abstract], 
 [Body], 

FROM 
 (SELECT  

 [Id], 
 [AddedDate], 
 [AddedBy], 
 -- The column aliases a and c allow us to refer to similarly names column unambiguously
 a.[CategoryId], 
 a.[Title], 
 c.[Title] as CategoryTitle,
 [Abstract], 
 [Body], 

--- This now includes an alias on the sortExpression order by
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.' + @sortExpression + ') as RowNum 

 FROM  [dbo].[Articles] a
 Join [dbo].[Category] c
 ON c.CategoryID = a.CategoryID
 WHERE c.CategoryId = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @CategoryId) + '

 ) as CategoryIdInfo 
 WHERE  
 ((RowNum between (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + ') AND ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + ' + ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @maximumRows) + ' - 1)  
   OR ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + ' = -1 OR ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @maximumRows) + ' = -1)' 

  -- Execute the SQL query 
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

What that does is declare an alias for both the Articles and the Category table (a and c respectively) that allows you to reference their columns unambiguously.

I haven't tried this with the exact case of using Row_Number but can think of no reason why it wouldn't work.

Then using the AS keyword should give you a unique name to use with your outer select.

Comment: David , I'm not good with sql , But i tried every way that came to my mind , This query Doesn't work . I knew how to use Alias , But the problem is I have two Select (select , , , ... from(,,,,Rownum.....)

Comment: Did you see the part of my answer talking about the AS keyword for the title column? I just tried this with a subselect and it works as expected, allowing both title columns to be selected.

Comment: Also, have you tried running just the inner query, with the Joins? I've always found that breaking things up into smaller queries can help clarify what is going on.

Comment: I appreciate David .
Yes, I have done like you before  , But unfortunately this query doesn't work either , by this query i have 5 both Invalid and Ambiguous column name

Comment: Could you please post you articles table structure too, as well as the query you are running that is failing with the join and the aliases.

Comment: David , You have Written :
FROM  [dbo].[Articles] a
 Join [dbo].[Category] c
 ON c.CategoryID = a.CategoryID 
While my Primary key in Category Table is Id , I fixed that But no answer again

Comment: Here is my Tables and StoredProcedure :
http://barnamenevis.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=42035&d=1262642856

Comment: Are there any columns with the same names in the two tables, that you are selecting, that you haven't aliased, or that you are using in your query? You need to use the alias **everywhere** that an ambiguous column is used

Comment: Mostafa - that is an arabic forum that appears to require a log in.

Comment: So, have you aliased id column in the select and the joins?

Comment: Ah! I think I've got it - you are dynamically inserting the Id column in your order by clauses. This will need to be aliased as well.

Comment: I upload here :
http://sites.google.com/site/dindarbiz/file-cabinet/StoredProcedureAndTables.rar?attredirects=0&d=1
I'm going crazy , It seems simple , But i don't know what's wrong .

Comment: Have you tried the sort expression? What happens when you replace that with a simple order by clause on a.id with no dynamicl sql for now?

Comment: It's necessary for storedProcedure to have sortExpression Parameter, it could be every thing even "space". When testing just need to pass "space" for sortExpression parameter

Comment: Mostafa, in your tables you have the following names in both tables: Id, AddedBy, AddedDate, Title, all of these will need to be aliased when you do the join. Did you alias AddedBy and AddedDate?

Comment: Also, could you please post the @sql that you execute which is failing. Or do you get the failure before executing?

Comment: It compile correctly , But error in running . There Error is :Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

I removed an extra "," after "Body" and before "From" + i edit " ON c.CategoryID = a.CategoryID" to "ON c.CategoryID = a.Id" But still Erros

Comment: Dear David , Could you look at the my question again , I edited , and posted a sample code again .